# Animate marker in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers, animation, angularjs, typescript

I have been trying to find a marker animation plugin for OpenLayers to sync lat, lon, and time data along a track like this (in Leaflet):

http://leafletplayback.theoutpost.io/examples/example_2.html

Basically i want to draw a line string and animate the first marker till the tend with timeline slider with speed control.
I have seen : https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html but it is confusing and doesn't meet my requirement.
Looking for a easy sample example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [example](https://viglino.github.io/ol3-ext/examples/map.featureanimation.path.html) of OL3 feature animation. It doesn't have a timeline slider but speed control and reverse animation. As a plus the example uses [gpx data](http://view-source:https://viglino.github.io/ol3-ext/examples/data/2009-09-04_rando.gpx) to animate a track.

It uses [featureanimation.js](https://github.com/Viglino/ol3-ext/blob/gh-pages/featureanimation/pathanimation.js) and can be used on a ol.layer.Vector *vector* and a ol.Feature *feature* applying a ol.Feature *path* like that:

```
vector.animateFeature (feature, 
    new ol.featureAnimation.Path({  
        path: path,
        easing: ol.easing['linear'],
        speed: 1.2
    });
});
```

Should be straight forward to connect the date/time values to a slider like jquery ui slider.

Comment: Please include key information in your answer so it does not lose all value due to link rot.

Comment: Different/New URL: The example is now available here: http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/animation/map.featureanimation.path.html